# Is it possible to use MS Access as a front-end and Google Cloud SQL as the back-end?

Tags: ms-access, google-cloud-sql

If so, what sort of VBA syntax is required? My Access application currently connects to a local SQL Server database, but I'm looking into moving things to the cloud.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

As long if the cloud provider allows external database connections, then a simple re-link that points the table links to the cloud version of MySQL should not require any changes to your existing code.

The only issue is depending on what cloud provider, you are not always allowed external connections outside of the cloud system/software. (so the hosted web system can used the hosted MySQL for example).

As far as I know, the google MySQL running in the cloud will allow external ODBC connections – there are steps that you must take to “open” up and allow such external connections. Once done, then the process of re-linking your Access tables to point to that cloud based system will not really be any different then what you are doing now.

The only issue to be aware is that you’re local LAN connection is about 100 times faster than you’re current over the internet connection. Even if the factor of speed is only 10 times less, then a 8 second operation you have now in Access will take 80 seconds to complete by using an over the internet connection.